# How do I preserve the color of a hyperlinked material icon

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm working on an Angular application and working with material icons for the first time.  I'm trying to display an 'email' icon, that is hyperlinked as a mailto as such:

```
<a href="mailto:trevor.goodchild@thecompany.com">
    <i class="material-icons">
      mail_outline
    </i>
</a>
```

So the icon without a hyperlink is just white with black outlines.  The black outline becomes blue when hyperlinked.  I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to just keep it black and white.

Comment: It's not visited though, it has the blue color on the initial load of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you get this side-effect, because of applying style for `a:link`

Try to set CSS `color` property directly to black for  element, that nests your material-icon, or remove style for `a:link`.